# Как убрать отступы между элементами, уменьшенными с помощью transform: scale?

Tags: css

Вот пример кода:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  
}

#first-child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
}

#second-child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first-child"></div>
  <div id="second-child"></div>
</div>
```

Между двумя прямоугольниками есть отступы, которое нужно убрать, это возможно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD:**

Тогда можно использовать относительное позиционирование для красного блока и придвинуть его к жёлтому:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}
#first-child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
#second-child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first-child"></div>
  <div id="second-child"></div>
</div>
```

---

Не очень понятно, что Вы подразумеваете под "отступами". Вы хотите, чтоб они примыкали друг к другу? Тогда просто измените для жёлтого блока свойство `transform-origin`:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}
#first-child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: right top;
}
#second-child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first-child"></div>
  <div id="second-child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Именно это расстояние мне и нужно уменьшить, но нужно, чтобы оба этих прямоугольника примыкали к левому верхнему краю, так можно сделать?

Comment: @Izzei-, я дополнил ответ